# My machine always connect to some strange foreign IP addresses

Tags: selinux

My machine installed Centos 6.4 without any special online services. Recently, my machine caused congestion on LAN. I'm a newbie to Linux, so I'm very confused.

I do not know what happened. Also maybe it is hacked!? Now I can't reinstall it for some reason.

I googled and tried something:

1/I used tcpdump and discovered that my machine always tries to connect to some strange foreign IP addresses, especially with port numbers constantly changing. That happens even when I disconnect my machine from LAN.

[image]

1/Next, I use netstat to check which process is making these connections. Result do not display PID/name of those processes.

[image]

My thought is to find these processes and kill them off. So how can I do that because netstat cannot find out PID/name.

Are there any other useful approaches?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Source port changing is normal: you just connect to https and you want to create new connections. Then most of the line may just be DNS resulution (8.8.8.8 is a google web server). Maybe you just connect to local DNS server (and using HTTPS), so probably browser configuration. If you do no trust your local ISP to know which domain you visit, maybe try to change configuration (and not using google).

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: please remove the pictures ... replace with the text ... just do copy and paste ... format the text as code for readability

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly comments, but space is limited.

1. Centos 6.4 has been out of support for over 3 years. Why are you still using it on an internet connected host?
2. If you check the IP addresses as well as the names in tcpdump then you might get some more clues as to what is happening - these do not look like unique PTR records / the default vhost may redirect to what is actually hosted there
3. What has this got to with selinux?
4. You could use iptables to redirect the connections to a local service, then tarpit the connection while you run netstat.